# read_callback() in Curl not working

Tags: c++, curl

```
static size_t read_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, fstream *stream)
{
  size_t total=size*nmemb; 
  stream->read(ptr,total);
  size_t bytes=(size_t)stream->gcount();
  cout<<bytes;
  return bytes;
}
```

it the conversion of read_callback() to c++ used in curl file uploading file.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Need more code. What exactly is your question. We cannot guess anything.

Comment: Are those the correct parameter types?